# DNS entries between Cloudflare and Route 53

Tags: dns, cloudflare, amazon-route53

We're trying to set up Cloudflare prior to our launch. We initially registered our domain with Route 53 and want to keep it there... For context, our servers are hosted by DigitalOcean

We set up Cloudflare and went through the flow about 24 hours ago. We changed the NS entries on Route 53 to Cloudflare.

However, when we go to sites like http://www.whoishostingthis.com/, it's still showing Digital Ocean.

We also have a subdomain - c.opencritic.com - for our image deploy pipeline. This is showing similar results.

Here are our current entries:

**ON ROUTE 53**

- A - opencritic.com - IP of server
- MX - opencritic.com - Gmail web servers
- NS - opencritic.com -Cloudflare name servers
- SOA - opencritic.com - long Amazon string during setup
- CNAME - c.opencritic.com - Alias of opencritic.com
- CNAME - www.opencritic.com - Alias of opencritic.com

**ON CLOUDLFARE**

- A - opencritic.com - IP of server
- CNAME - c.opencritic.com - Alias of opencritic.com
- CNAME - www.opencritic.com - Alias of opencritic.com

What are we missing?? Why aren't we being routed through Cloudflare?

Cheers,
Matthew

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved...

Route53 has two different places for DNS records: the actual name servers listed on the domain registration page, and the NS records.

We had editted the second, but not the first.

Comment: You solved it by editing the nameservers on the domain registration page.  What you may not yet have realized is that changing NS records in your hosted zone was technically wrong, but also, it didn't do anything meaningful -- because your hosted zone is no longer doing anything.  Changing the nameservers to CloudFlare has made all the hosted zone entries in Route 53 invisible to the Internet unless you have duplicated then in CloudFlare's DNS management tools.

Comment: ...so, for example, your MX records will begin to fail, soon, unless you duplicate them on CloudFlare.  Only one system can be authoritative for DNS on a given domain, unless there is a mechanism for delegation in place, which is typically only practical at the subdomain level.